# Is it possible to tell if an entity is tracked?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1. I've implemented a base repository using lots of the examples online. My repository get methods take a bool parameter to decide whether to track the entities. Sometimes, I want to load an entity and track it, other times, for some entities, I simply want to read them and display them (i.e. in a graph). In this situation there is never a need to edit, so I don't want the overhead of tracking them. Also, graph entities are sent to a silverlight client, so the entities are disconnected from the context. Hence my Get methods can return a list of entities that are either tracked or not. This is achieved dynamically creating the query as follows:

```
DbQuery<E> query = Context.Set<E>();

 // Track the entities in the context?
 if (!trackEntities)
 {
    query = query.AsNoTracking();
 }
```

However, I now want to enable the user to interact with the graph and edit it. This will not happen very often, so I still want to get some entities without tracking them but to have the ability to save them. To do this I simply attach them to the context and set the state as modified. Everything is working so far.

I am auditing any changes by overriding the SaveChanges method. As explained above I may, in some low cases, need to save modified entities that were disconnected. So to audit, I have to retrieve the current values from the database and then compare to work out what was changed while disconnected. If the entity has been tracked, there is no need to get the old values, as I've got access to them via the state manager. I'm not using self tracking entities, as this is overkill for my requirements.

QUESTION: In my auditing method I simply want to know if the modified entity is tracked or not, i.e. do I need to go to the db and get the original values?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679172(v=vs.103).aspx) returns DbEntityEntry objects for all tracked entities. DbEntityEntry has Entity property that you could use to find out whether the entity is tracked. Something like

```
var isTracked = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => Object.ReferenceEquals(e.Entity, myEntity));
```

Comment: Can't seem to be able to edit your answer since it doesn't have enough characters. First of all, thanks for getting me in the right direction! It should be `var isTracked = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => Object.ReferenceEquals(e.Entity, myEntity))` these days though

Comment: Updated as per your comment,